# Finding the Pythagorean triplet that sums to 1000

Tags: python, optimization, beginner, project-euler, mathematics

[Project Euler problem 9](http://projecteuler.net/problem=9) says:

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, *a* < *b* < *c*,
>   for which,
>
> *a*<sup>2</sup> + *b*<sup>2</sup> = *c*<sup>2</sup>
>
> For example, 3<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5<sup>2</sup>.
>
> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which *a* + *b* + *c* =
>   1000. Find the product *abc*.

I am a beginner in programming, especially Python. I got the answer for the problem, but how can I optimize it?

```
a=0
b=a+1
exit=False

#a loop
for x in xrange(1000):
    a+=1
    b=a+1
    c=b+1
    #b loop
    for y in xrange(1000):
        b+=1            
        if(1000-b-a < 0):
            break
        c = 1000-a-b
        if(a**2 + b**2 == c**2):    
                print "The number is ", a*b*c
                x=1000
                exit = True
        else:
                print "A is ", a ,".\n B is ", b, ".\n  C is ",c,"."
        if exit:
                break
    if exit:
            break
```

Comment: Any optimizations that you could make would likely be in removing the O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: This is [Project Euler Problem 9](http://projecteuler.net/problem=9).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you got the answer, but your code could be tidier.  The main weaknesses I see are:

- **Too many variables:** The problem calls for numbers *a*, *b*, and *c*.  Introducing variables `x` and `y` needlessly complicates the code.  It's always the case that `a = x + 1`, so `x` is redundant.  Then, with `y` (but not really using `y`), you loop up to 1000 times with `b` starting from `a + 1`.

  Your loop structure can be distilled down to…

  ```
  for a in xrange(1, 1001):
      for b in xrange(a + 1, a + 1001):
          if a + b > 1000:
              break
          c = 1000 - a - b
          # etc.
  ```

  However, the if-break could still be improved upon — see below.
- **Using variables for flow control:** It's cumbersome to set an `exit` flag, then have code elsewhere inspect the flag.  There are more assertive techniques to go where you want to go immediately.  You want to break out from a nested loop, so search Stack Overflow and read [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189645/1157100).

As previously mentioned, there is an even better way to enumerate possibilities for `a`, `b`, and `c` such that their sum is always 1000.  That way, you don't need the if-break in your code.

```
def euler9():
    # Ensure a < c
    for c in xrange(2, 1000):
        for a in xrange(1, c):
            # Ensure a + b + c == 1000.  Since a is counting up, the first
            # answer we find should have a <= b.
            b = 1000 - c - a

            # Ensure Pythagorean triple
            if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
                print("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d.  abc = %d" % (a, b, c, a * b * c))
                return

euler9()
```

Alternatively:

```
def euler9():
    for a in xrange(1, 1000):
        for b in xrange(a + 1, 1000 - a):
            # Ensure a + b + c == 1000.  Since b is counting up, the first
            # answer we find should have b <= c.
            c = 1000 - a - b
            # etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some changes I would do in your code:

1. Since you already have two variables `x` and `y` from the loop, you don't need `a` and `b`.  Get the 3 numbers as - `x`, `y`, and `1000 - x - y`, and use them.
2. You might well possibly be checking the values same pythagorean triplets twice. Once with `x`, `y`, and `1000 - x - y`, and then with `y`, `x`, `1000 - y - x`. For example, when `x` takes `2` and `y` takes `3`, then you don't want to check this again for `x = 3` and `y = 2`. This might happen, as your inner loop is running from the beginning every time. You can avoid this by iterating from `x` to `1000`.
3. No need of `exit` `boolean` variable. Put those loops inside some function, and return as soon as the result is found.

*Modified Code:*

```
def specialPythagoreanTriplet(s):

    for a in xrange(s):
        for b in xrange(a, s):
            c = s - a - b;
            if a**2 + b**2 = c**2:
                return (a, b, c)
```

In addition to all that, you don't really need to iterate till `1000` for values of `a` and `b`. The maximum value that `a` could take should be much less than `1000`. Let's find out.

You have:

> a + b + c = 1000, and
>   a < b < c

Replace `b` and `c` with `a`, we get:

> a + a + a < 1000
>   3a < 1000
>   a < 333

Similarly, you can find out the threshold for `b`, I'm leaving it for you:

```
for a in xrange(s / 3):
    for b in xrange(a + 1, s):  # Change `s` to someother value
        # Same as previous code.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the fastest solution:

```
print "The number is 31875000"
```

In all seriousness, you have several constraints you can throw in. WLOG, a <= b. We also know a,b < c. We know that a + b + c = 1000. So a < 334. If a = 100, then b < 450.

I will also say that since this is a Project Euler question you can probably find some very clever solutions on the Project Euler thread. I imagine this problem can be done pretty quickly by hand with the right maths.

Comment: lol, I know the answer and my code works. I just want an optimized version. Your suggestion will also be taken. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used information here and it seems to solve fairly quickly:

[Euclid's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)

```
a = m^2 - n^2 , b = 2mn , c = m^2 + n^2
```

For math related questions, using the correct formula can save quite a lot of computation.

In regard to your current code, you can probably avoid setting the a, b, c in the outer loop, and b in the inner loop if you change your 'for x in xrange' to 'for a in xrange' and your 'for y in xrange' to 'for b in xrange'.  This is a pretty common way to advance those values and saves quite a bit of moving the numbers in python.  Less work done is faster. :)

Using the Euler formula above is likely much faster though.  You may want to consider how you would cycle through values m and n and calculate a,b,c.

Comment: True, but it's only faster if you disregard the time to write and debug your program. A computer can easily iterate 1000 x 1000 times in less than one second.